# Trade stocks for stocks without involving cash

Tags: taxes, stocks, broker

As I'm trading stocks, most of my transactions are selling stocks that have gains and immediately investing in other stocks. I wonder why there isn't a platform that allows you to just trade stock for a stock without having to sell and realizing gains. An example transaction would be trading 10 shares of stock a for 5 of stock B an 2 of stock C. Is it because uncle sam wants the money? These sort of transactions don't have the wherewithal to pay, as at no point I am keeping the cash. I was just wondering what your opinions are and if maybe there is a service that allows you to trade stock for stock without converting to cash and realizing intermediary gains and offsetting losses. I believe that for most investors that will simplify the tax greatly.

Comment: Why would you consider trading stock for stock not "realizing gains"? If I bought stock for $100 and exchanged it for stock worth $200, why is that not "realizing" a gain?

Comment: @DStanley that is a good point, I agree it is a gain but it should be a deferred one as I didn't receive cash, therefore, don't have the wherewithal to pay the tax. At the point where I decide to convert it to cash, I should pay the tax. Similar to 401k you don't pay tax on an investment you cannot convert to cash and use until you retire and start using it.

Comment: You are taxed on the *value* of the gain when you dispose of the asset, whether you received cash or another stock in return.

Comment: @chepner I don't think that is true for all cases especially if you don't have the wherewithal to pay the tax. As an example if I have a 10k gain on bitcoin if I sell it, then I have to pay tax.   If I use it to purchase a car, I am not aware of being required to pay tax.

Comment: For tax purposes, I'm not sure bitcoin counts as a currency at all.

Comment: @chepner that's beyond the point just trying to give an example.

Comment: @dono "If I use bitcoin to buy a car, I am not aware of being required to pay tax". You absolutely are. Absolutely, 100%, you are. If you buy BTC at a day when it is worth 1k USD, and then use it to buy a car when the value rises to 40k, you need to report a 39k USD gain on your tax return.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Interesting, I didn't know that. By that same rule would it be fair to use inflation as a loss? Just for discussion.

Comment: No, because currency and capital assets are two different things.

Comment: @dono No, because USD *Is the currency of paying US taxes*, and crypto is an asset in the eyes of the IRS. However you could claim losses on GBP, for example, if you held onto it and the GBP weakened.

Comment: @chepner forget what you have been taught and just think what would be fair I wasn't looking for a definite answer just an opinion. Besides crypto is a currency not a capital asset

Comment: @dono GBP is an asset for US tax purposes. USD is an asset for UK tax purposes. Crypto is an asset for tax purposes in the US and UK. Keep in mind that since you are coming at this from the crypto-angle, where 'cross-buying' is common, that is currently done for fiat currencies two, because they are incredibly liquid and fungible, whereas equity shares are not.

Comment: @DonO Just because bitcoin calls itself a currency doesn't mean it *is* one.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be based on the desire to continue to defer recognition of taxable income by avoiding receipt of cash. However, in any jurisdiction I'm aware of, trading one stock for another [ie: if you did this manually by for example trading a share of apple for the equivalent value of shares in Tesla, with a friend] would still be considered taxable, whether you received cash or not. *

In some cases, you may be able to defer such gains, but in all cases I am aware of, that would allow for the use of cash as an intermediary exchange.

Moreover, to answer your question - this would vaaastly reduce the interested market in your transaction. Want to sell a share of Apple for cash? Great! There is a line of people with pre-announced intentions to buy Apple for an exact $ figure, and you can immediately take them up on that offer through electronic exchanges accessed by your broker. But if you want to trade 30 shares of Apple for ~6 shares of Tsla, then what happens to the difference in value? Are you only going to make the trade if the ratio is exactly perfect? How do you declare your intention, etc..

There is are many reasons cash is used as a medium of exchange. This is an example for that.

**As a side note, if you are asking this question because you are in the practice of trading different crypto currencies for other cryptos, you should probably know that that is taxable, whether get USD for it or not.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am mainly asking because I find it interesting that such a financial vehicle does not exist. Regarding the point, you make about not being able to evenly complete transactions because shares don't add up there would be fractional shares. Fractional shares already exist in Robinhood and some newer brokers. With fractional shares, you should be able to not have that problem.

Comment: @dono I don't know why you find it odd - if there are say 100,000 [0.03% of Americans] people who would buy 10 shares of Apple, and of those say 10,000 [0.003% of Americans] would pay $120 for them, and say 1,000,000 who want to sell a share of Tesla, and say 100,000 [0.03% of Americans] who want $600 for that share, then assuming such decisions are made equally across the US population, then only 300M * 0.03% * 0.003% = 27 people in the US who would theoretically want to do your exact matching. Think of the drop in liquidity from 100,000 buyers to just 27, to no benefit I can see.

Comment: I agree that such trades won't be near as liquid as cash and orders might take time to fill. That's a good point but might not be a complete dealbreaker.

Comment: @dono to what benefit - you call it not a dealbreaker [but for many traders, turning seconds to trade into weeks or more would be horrendous], but what benefit is there in doing what you proposed? As I mentioned the tax impact would be identical, so what benefit is there, that any loss of liquidity, no matter how slight, would be suffered?

Comment: @ Grade 'Eh' Bacon If the tax won't change then this discussion is over, and there is no benefit in doing what I am saying. The only benefit would be if the tax is deferred on such trades.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the tax question, I believe both the stock and bitcoin examples would fall under the IRS regulations on [bartered goods](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/four-things-you-should-know-if-you-barter), where any gains (or losses) have tax implications.

Without the tax benefit, any discussion about trading stock-for-stock has all of the pitfalls that 'Eh' brings up, with the near-complete lack of liquidity being the most problematic (to me).